# if my device has logged into someones gmail, will it still show on device list after being factory reset?

Tags: factory-reset, android-device-manager, remote-wipe

someone that i was friends with in a phone game decided he hates me and recently factory reset my phone and my tablet remotely through a shared gmail account. that part is over and done, but we shared more than one gmail account and i want to prevent him from doing it to me again.

I would think that when my devices were reset it would remove them from all accounts that they were logged into, but wanted to be sure that he will not still see my devices logged in on any of the shared accounts.

i have not added those accounts to either device again, the only account added is my private account.

Answer (score 0):

*Your question is a little unclear so let me know if i got this right.*

You were logged in as abc@gmail.com on your tablet/tablets and your friend, being that he had access to this email address, went ahead and deleted everything in your phone, and now you are wondering if he's able to do the same again?

The answer is no, he's not able to wipe your phone again, because when he erased it in the first time, that cleared everything, including all accounts. And as long as you don't add that account back, he won't be able to do any harm.

You can double check this, by going to settings>accounts>Google, and see if "abc@gmail.com" is still there.